# Windows Service not using 64-bit Dll's

Tags: vb.net, service, 64-bit

I have a service application that was developed on 32-bit (for 32-bit OS) and I am trying to port it over to 64-bit.  It's a simple application, so doesn't appear there should be much to do.  HOWEVER - The SDK I am using (Proficy Historian SDK)  has both a 32-bit and 64-bit version.

When I installed the service to run it on a 64-bit machine I got a COM error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {54D8AB6D-A946-445E-BE18-F5B9387D1DD4} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

This relates to that SDK, of course.

**TEST APPLICATION**

NOW:  I took that service and created a Forms application with 2 buttons which control OnStart and OnStop.  That application has no problem working if:

Platform = Any CPU
Target CPU = AnyCPU

OR

Platform = Any CPU
Target CPU = x86

HOWEVER:  If Target CPU is ever x64, it won't work :(

**BACK TO THE SERVICE**

And no matter what I seem to do with the service, it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Your assumption that the 64-bit version is installed appears incorrect.  Or they released a *new* version and you built your program for the old one.  Be sure to use the type library from the 64-bit release of the product.

Comment: Why does it work with the forms application and *not* the service application, then?